# Laravel Eloquent foreach

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

I'm trying to make a seperate table in the blade file for each driver with their scheduled moves. I'm trying to accomplish this by foreaching through drives in the comtroller. I could setup a seperate query in the controller for each driver but that will require a lot of maintenance should we add or delete drivers.

Please help me understand how to accomplish this - below is what I currently have:

CONTROLLER

```
"Trucking::DRIVERS" is the constant in my model with the names of the drivers.
```

```
public function overview()
    {
        $drivers = Trucking::DRIVERS;

        foreach($drivers as $driver) {
            $truckings = Trucking::query()
                ->where('truck', $driver)
                ->where('active', 1)
                ->where('status', 'scheduled')
                ->orderBy('trucking_date_requested')
                ->orderBy('order')
                ->get();
        }

        return view('trucking.overview', compact('driver', 'truckings'));
    }
```

BLADE FILE:

```
    @foreach($driver as $table)
    <div class="flex-col space-y-4">
        <x-table>
            <x-slot name="head">
                <x-table.heading>Date</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>Order</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>Status</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>Type</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>Model</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>SN</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>From</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>City</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>To</x-table.heading>
                <x-table.heading>City</x-table.heading>
            </x-slot>

            <x-slot name="body">
                @foreach($truckings as $trucking)
                    <x-table.row
                        class="odd:bg-gray-100 hover:bg-yellow-100"
                        title="{{ $trucking->note }}"
                    >
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->trucking_date_requested }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->order }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>
                            <span class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full {{ App\Models\Trucking::SORTING[$trucking->sorting] }}">
                                {{ $trucking->status }}
                            </span>
                    </x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->type }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->model }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->sn }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->from_name }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->from_city }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->to_name }}</x-table.cell>
                    <x-table.cell>{{ $trucking->to_city }}</x-table.cell>
                    </x-table.row>
                @endforeach
            </x-slot>
        </x-table>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller file, you can create a custom array to which you will push driver and his truckings. It should look something like this:

```php
$data = []
$drivers = Trucking::DRIVERS;
foreach($drivers as $driver) {
   $truckings = Trucking::query()
   ->where('truck', $driver)
   ->where('active', 1)
   ->where('status', 'scheduled')
   ->orderBy('trucking_date_requested')
   ->orderBy('order')
   ->get();
   array_push($data, [
     'driver' => $driver,
     'truckings' => $truckings,
   ])
}

return view('trucking.overview')->with(['data' => $data]);
```

Now in your blade, you can actually foreach your data variable, render the table based on `$data['driver']` (this will be a driver object) and then render the drivers truckings by using `$data['truckings']` (this will be a collection of trucking objects).

Comment: Thank you lyyka. Works great.